# Dealing with Chinese characters in C string manipulation

Tags: c, string, encoding, cjk

It is known that in C, a string is represented by an array of `char`s.

And in most 32-bit processors, a `char` takes one byte or eight bits. And a string consists of an array of one `byte`s.

Because extended characters like Chinese and Japanese takes up **more** bits than 8 bits, I am getting a little confused about the stuff around this.

For example, I tested that I can define an array of Chinese characters the same way an array of English letters is defined, using syntax like`char array[100]`. So my question is:

Is there a mechanism that attempts to bridge the gap between general 8-bits characters and greater-than-8-bits characters so that they are treated like the same, just like what I have mentioned above.

Comment: You should probably use wchar_t instead, this explains a little more about wide characters and their use in C/C++. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character#C.2FC.2B.2B

Comment: You need to research what is called MBCS or Multi-Byte Character Sets.

Comment: @JesusRamos: The `wchar_t` type (rather, code that uses it) is not really very portable, since you don't know what encoding it uses, or whether it even supports Unicode.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using multi-byte character encodings. This is a rather wide subject, but start with the following:

- [wchar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc)
- [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)
- [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (which allows manipulating strings with the char based functions).

Comment: Note that `wchar` is almost never the right choice, since it's not really portable.  (Because you don't know what encoding it uses.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the UTF8 string encoding, as it makes possible to use normal (byte <= 127) characters as usually, and in addition, you'll be able to use the two-, three-, or four-byte characters by detecting an Unicode control character (byte >= 128). You also can use libiconv for some related problems. http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/